# One of my pages is not facebook shareable

Tags: facebook, web-crawler, meta-tags, sharing

I want to share this two receipts on facebook. The first just works, the second one does not show any preview, when pasted into facebook. I can't see the difference between them. Why does the first one work, the second one does not:

http://www.vegantastic.de/#!Rezept:Kartoffel-Bohnen-Curry
http://www.vegantastic.de/#!Rezept:Gnocchetti-Sardi-a-la-mac-n-Cheese

In the facebook debugger (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/) both URLs are correctly read and the facebook crawler can read all the meta tags it needs.

I am using a ajax hash tag crawling approach and the hashtags are replaced by "?_escaped_fragment_=". So the crawler sees these URLs:

http://www.vegantastic.de/?_escaped_fragment_=Rezept:Kartoffel-Bohnen-Curry
http://www.vegantastic.de/?_escaped_fragment_=Rezept:Gnocchetti-Sardi-a-la-mac-n-Cheese

@CBroe Thats very strange, scraping works fine for me:

[image]

Comment: I’m currently only seeing an error message in debug tool, saying _“Curl Error : OPERATION_TIMEOUTED Operation timed out after 10000 milliseconds with 0 bytes received”_ when trying to scrape both of those URLs.

Comment: @CBroe It works for me, see updated post